# jQuery-Ajax Calls Fail Over Basic Authentication

Tags: jquery, web2py

I have 2 Web2Py applications, let me call them *Provider* and *Receiver*. *Provider* offers basic authentication features, and *Receiver* uses it to log in. Users have been created in a database local to *Provider* and *Receiver* is successfully logging in using those user credentials. But when I have RESTful methods in my controller(s), jQuery-Ajax call to them only work if I manually log in to *Provider* also through the same browser session using the same username. If I do not do that and only login from *Receiver*, it says successfully logged in, but does not successfully carry out Ajax GET calls. If I login to *Reciever* using one username, and to *Provider* using a different username, Ajax GET fetches information of the user logged in to *Provider*. I put this as script in `index.html` of *Receiver*:

```
var gBaseUrl="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Provider/sites/";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      async: true,
      url: gBaseUrl+"get_username",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
        $('#ContentView').append('<p> succeeded '+data+'</p>');
      }
      failure: function(data){
        $('#ContentView').append('<p> failed '+data+'</p>');
      }
    });
});
```

This adds nothing to ContentView if I do not log in to *Provider* locally. This is how *Provider*'s `db.py` looks like:

```
## configure auth policy
auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = True
auth.settings.reset_password_requires_verification = True
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
auth.settings.controller = 'default'
auth.settings.hmac_key = None
auth.settings.mailer = None
auth.settings.login_after_registration = False
```

To achieve basic authentication, *Provider*'s `default.py` has this:

```
def basic_auth():
    """
    checks if the user is logged in and returns True/False.
    if so user is in auth.user as well as in session.auth.user
    """
    auth.basic()
    if auth.user:
        print("login success!")
        print(auth.user.username, " is logging in!")
        session.forget()
        return True
    else:
        print("login failed!")
        return False
```

And then to return the username, in *Provider*'s `site` controller, I have:

```
@request.restful()
@auth.requires_login()
def get_username():
    def GET():
        return str(auth.user.username)
    return locals()
```

ContentView is nothing but an empty `div` that I have in the `index.html`.

I also modified the `requires` decorator's implementation slightly in `gluon/tools.py`:

```
if current.request.ajax:
    raise HTTP(401)
...
elif self.settings.allow_basic_login_only or \
        basic_accepted or current.request.is_restful:
    raise HTTP(401, **{'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="My Realm"'})
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log in via basic authentication, you need to provide the login credentials in the HTTP headers of the request, which your Ajax code does not do. In any case, a better option would probably be to use the built-in [Central Authentication Service](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09#Central-Authentication-Service) functionality. Since you're making Ajax requests from the browser, the session cookie will get sent with the requests, so there's no reason to limit yourself to basic authentication.

UPDATE: If you need to use basic authentication, note that the jQuery [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method takes `username` and `password` arguments. It also allows you to set the headers directly. You could also have the server send a 401 response and let the browser handle the prompt for credentials, but that isn't the best user experience.

Also, if the Provider app will be running on a different domain, keep in mind that browsers impose a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) on Ajax requests. In that case, you'll need to implement [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: I am doing this experiment to text the functionality, but later I will have to replace the _Provider_ app with an actual server that only allows basic authentication, so I do not have the liberty to choose.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the print statement in the `basic_auth()` method in _Provider_'s default controller returns the correct username when I remotely log in. But jQuery-Ajax calls fail.

Comment: Again, your jQuery-Ajax call is not providing any login credentials in the HTTP header, so it isn't even attempting to do basic authentication. Also, note that your basic_auth() function is decorated with `@auth.requires_login()`, so you have to be logged in already in order to access that function.

Comment: I am not using jQuery-Ajax to authenticate. I thought it should be done by `auth.settings.login_methods = [basic_auth('http://127.0.0.1:8000/Provider')]`, which is already in the model of _Receiver_. When I make that call, I am already supposed to be authenticated, and my _Receiver_ app tells me I am logged in. So what am I doing wrong?

That `@auth.requires_login()` was a silly mistake. Have removed it. Problem is still there.

Comment: With `auth.settings.login_methods = [basic_auth('http://127.0.0.1:8000/Provider')]`, you are simply telling the Receiver app to log in its users by making a basic authentication request to the Provider app. When a user logs in to the Receiver app, they are not logged into the Provider app -- the Provider app is only being used to tell the Receiver app if the user is allowed to access *the Receiver app*. If you want to make Ajax requests to the Provider app that require basic authentication from the Provider app, then see my answer above.

Comment: I am not sure if this should be treated as an extension to this question or I should start a different question, but I actually do not understand how the password will end up in the Ajax call as a regular string. Is the password not one-way hashed? Or am I supposed to send the hash with Ajax GET?

Comment: Instead of creating a modal login, can I just Ajax call my local app (_Receiver_), which then augments the user data and redirects the call to _Provider_? I think this would be smarter. But I cannot find any examples where this is done.

Comment: Passwords are not hashed with [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (which is why HTTPS is recommended for such requests). It might be easier if you ask about this on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/web2py).

Comment: I have asked it [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/web2py/023HDuptn8A/discussion). Let's see what comes of it.